# "Google Now" Patent Application Number

Tags: application, uspto, google, wipo

I've been looking for Google's patent application number for "Google Now", the intelligent assistant but with no success. Can any redirect me to the correct link or post the Patent number? Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not expert in electronics but I feel below is the patent covers the same_

1. Title:-Providing digital content based on expected user behavior 
   [US8271413](http://www.google.co.in/patents/US8271413)
2. Providing results to parameterless search queries [US8478519](https://www.google.com/patents/US8478519)
3. Providing results to parameterless search queries [US8504286](https://www.google.com/patents/US8504286)
4. Activating Applications Based on Accelerometer Data [US8065508](https://www.google.com/patents/US8065508), US8438373, US8464036, US8886921.

they might have some design patents

Comment: Im not sure if this is what I was looking for but thank you anyway. I'll keep looking and if anything comes up I post it here or if I find out that this is the correct one I'll mark it as correct.. Thank you once more for your time!

Comment: @snksnk check the figures of all patents

Comment: First of all thank you for your time, and time spent on this. I've been searching for 2 days now and all I found is scattered pieces of this software. These is no single document to it, like Apple's SIRI. All the technical characteristics are in several patents.

Comment: In efficient patent management its good strategy to file many patents